# What type of gestures or other controls do Windows Phone 8 apps typically use for deletion?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, user-experience, longlistselector

I'm an iOS developer who uses an Android device who has recently started Windows Phone 8 development. I have a `LongListSelector` in a `Pivot` control, and I want to give users the ability to delete items from the `LongListSelector`.

What type of gestures and other controls do Windows Phone 8 apps usually use to delete items?

On iOS it's typical to swipe to remove an item from a list (not applicable in this situation due to the `Pivot`) and on Android it's typical to long-press to show a delete button in a context menu (in addition to the swipe-to-remove also used in iOS).

Are there equivalent gestures or conventions used in Windows Phone 8 apps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Context menu:

1. Hold on item
2. Show context menu with delete command
3. Tap delete command to remove item

http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/BR208693

Selection:

1. Tap left of item to multi-select items (show checkbox after tapping left)
2. Show delete button in application bar when in selection mode
3. Tap on delete button to remove items

Alternative: Button in application bar for selection mode / show selection checkboxes

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff431813(v=vs.105).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff431813%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

What else?